# How to find a patch with a specific ID where there is a red turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem with this code piece.

```
ask persons [
set my-ID-polygon [ID-polygon] of patch-here
[patch-here] of turtles with [color = red and shape = "x"] with [ID-polygon = my-ID-polygon] ]
```

I obtain this error message:

```
TURTLES breed does not own variable MY-ID-POLYGON
```

In fact, I would like to have the patch with ID-polygon = my-ID-polygon where there is a turtle with color = red and shape = "x".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *guess* that `my-ID-polygon` is a `persons` variable, but in the following expression:

```
turtles with [color = red and shape = "x"] with [ID-polygon = my-ID-polygon]
```

The second `with` clause is executed in the context of `turtles`.

That being said, if you want:

> the patch with ID-polygon = my-ID-polygon where there is a turtle with color = red and shape = "x"

It translates to something like this in NetLogo code:

```
ask persons [
  show one-of patches with [
    ID-polygon = [ my-ID-polygon ] of myself and
    any? (turtles-here with [ color = red and shape = "x" ])
  ]
]
```

I use [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) in case many patches fit the criteria.

The `with` clause is executed in the context of patches. In order to get the value of the `my-ID-polygon` variable of the asking person, you need to "move up" to the outer context using `of myself`.